# What features would you add in a better web browser?

Tags: browser, web

I am currently reading Paul Graham's book "Hackers And Painters" and he mentioned in it that a good way to change the world would be to write a new Mosaic(web browser). He also mentioned in his 2004 online essay saying that current web browsers suck, quote : "If someone sat down and wrote a web browser that didn't suck (a fine idea, by the way), the world would be that much richer."

Here's the link to another online 2014 essay by Hamish McKenzie saying that current web browsers suck : http://pando.com/2013/12/24/why-do-mobile-browsers-suck-so-bad/

Wanted to get your thoughts on this issue and how to make a much better web browser that users would love ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a solicitation for user-experience-related design requirements for a web browser, rather than a question about a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the browser, but the way people manage it.

In the early days of Internet we were perfectly happy with text-only pages, but now people want glittering web pages "as-seen-on-TV".

My philosophy is to give more importance to the content rather than to the container, so I often use [lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) to visit websites too much overcharged with banners and ads. Living in a rural area with a painfully slow connection, to download a couple of Mb to read less than 1 Kb of useful text doesn't seems to me a bright use of the Net.

Comment: Hi Marco, I am using a SamSung cellphone and searching for stuff on Google using the pre-installed mobile web browser is a lousy experience.It's slow, buggy and unintuitive. When you click on the search bar, the mobile keypad has a bad habit of popping up and disappearing. The keypad buttons are way too small for human fingers and you have to pay extra attention when typing so that you dont hit the character next to it.And the interface is ugly. Whichever group builds a better mobil phone with an intuitive interface better than Samsung is going to get really rich.

Comment: Smartphones with a single screen are a temporary technology. I forecast a bendable screen, offering a 7" display on a phone the size of a Galaxy Pocket with folding side wings, like medieval triptychs. Maybe not next year, anyway. At that point any desktop browser will be almost fine.

Comment: God knows how technology will evolve in the future ... maybe we will see flying cars being invented by Google Anyway, I am planning to learn programming from scratch because I want to build a successful startup that I can sell to Google or Microsoft for a huge sum of money (!!!) What technologies do you suggest I learn and what kinds of great startup ideas are there left to work on ? Thanks alot .... Cai GengYang

Comment: Before to know **how** to make something, it is more important to know **what** to do, so you can choose the most appropriate tool: a bulldozer is not very useful for paint scraping! I suggest you to look for a library with an updated copy of the whole "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming - and to read it all, to have a good knowledge of algorithms. After that reading you will be able to use almost every programming language, even those not yet written.

Comment: I am currently programming in Python ... I have downloaded the launcher and see it running ... (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\py.exe) I see a list of texts appearing in quick succession, like [67/392/2] test_codeop , [118/392/5] test_faulthandler and [168/392/6] test_importlib ... new texts keep appearing in quick succession ... it keeps going on and on. I want to create a better web browser than the ones currently in existence (one of Paul Graham's ideas for a startup ... ) Can I code something this using purely Python and how do I go about doing it ? Thanks alot.

Comment: I have changed my mind and decided to work on an equally interesting but much smaller project (a car-sharing realtime mobile app), an idea I stole from a website : http://www.ideaswatch.com/startup-idea/car-sharing-realtime-mobile-app?hc_location=ufi